# How to get only the outer shape of the object

Tags: selection-tools, select

Is there any way to mark only the outer part of an object (attachment) and remove the entire center? The problem is that the parts into which the object is divided are partially visible outside, but they are also part of the interior.

The point is, I want to get only the outer shape of the object itself, without the inner elements (empty inside).

[image]

[image]

Comment: How would you define "outer shape"? It seems like a very subjective definition, considering that some "inside" parts are visible from the outside.

Comment: Sorry for not clear description.

The object consists of several parts - some are completely hidden inside, some are partially visible from the outside.

What I want to achieve is to get just the outer shell of the whole object, empty inside.

Hope this is more understandable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could merge all objects with a boolean, then try a Geometry Nodes with multiple raycasts, either like I do below, with some offsets from the normal, or by chaining the raycasts by making a 2nd raycast from where the first raycast hits and so on...

[image]

*"normal raycast"*:

[image]

The thing is, if you have holes in your geometry, through which you can see the inside, it's a matter or luck if the rays will manage to escape from the inside of the object versus just a concave part of the surface - the smaller the holes the more bias in favor of the concave surface, and the more surface, the less randomness and more reliable results. For a Suzanne with solidify and inner faces marked red, using my setup gives:

[image]

Notice how both a face on the ear that shouldn't be removed, got removed, and a red face inside that should be removed, passed the raycast test.